# What is significant of cascading in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Why we are using cascading in Java?? What is its importance.
Here i am using for save and update

```
Stock stock = new Stock();
StockDailyRecord stockDailyRecords = new StockDailyRecord();
//set the stock and stockDailyRecords  data

stockDailyRecords.setStock(stock);        
stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords);

session.save(stock);
session.save(stockDailyRecords);
```

Is there any alternate way for cascading.?

Comment: As the site where your example can be found tells, _cascade_ keyword can be used to avoid having to persist each sub-element "manually" : see : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/

Comment: Hi Berger for more understanding i am asking this question .

Answer (score 1):

Cascade attribute transfers operations done on one object onto its related child objects. if we write cascade = “all” then all operations like insert, delete, update at parent object will be effected to child object also